# Can Applescript record the CURRENT setting of a Preference in iTunes?

Tags: applescript, itunes-app

I need to remember the **original** setting of the **iTunes Media Folder Location** setting so I can restore its value after changing it (possibly) more than once.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Give us a clue.... your question implies you know how to change it already so spill the beans and tell us the half of the story you know...

Comment: I use code that clicks each menu option "iTunes > Preferences > Advanced Tab > Change Button > Each directory in a path provided on the command line then the OK Button

Comment: The path is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iApps.plist`

Comment: vadian - Do you know the Key's name? It would make getting the value with Applescript much easier.

Comment: Can't you look it up yourself? Copy the path, goto Finder, press ⇧⌘G, press ⌘V, press Return, press Space.

Comment: It did not find it even after I shortened the search term to just the last element in the given path

Comment: Do **exactly** what I suggested in the last comment and you'll get a QuickLook of the file.

Comment: @vadian - I opened the plist in Xcode and had it do a find for "iTunes%20Music" and it found **NOTHING**. I then scanned the file myself and still couldn't find it, just a reference to the root directory "~/iTunes%20Store%20Only".

Comment: Maybe Apple changed that. In my `iApps.plist` file there are a file URL and a path to the iTunes library. In `com.apple.iTunes.plist` there is a key `alis:1:iTunes Library Location` with an NSData object representing the alias specifier to the iTunes folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.apple.iApps.plist is the correct place to look.

The key "iTunesRecentDatabasePaths" is a String Array, item 0 holds the most recent entry in a form relative to the User's Home directory. Meaning it will probably start with a ~ character.

The key "iTunesRecentDatabases" is a String Array, item 0 holds the most recent entry in the form of a fully qualified "File://" URL.